# swift3，my timer can't stop. why?

Tags: ios, swift

this is i seting a timer function, the code like this:

```
@IBAction func start(_ sender: UIButton) {

    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1,
                         target: self,
                         selector:#selector(ViewController.action),
                         userInfo: nil,
                         repeats: true)
}

@objc func action() {

    hoursMinutesSeconds()
    if stop == true{
        start = false
        timer.invalidate()
        timer.invalidate()
        time = 0 
    }
}

@IBAction func stop(_ sender: UIButton){

    start = false
    timer.invalidate()
    timer.invalidate()
    time = 0           
}
```

but, when i click the stop func,  this function not work. mean is the timer not stop. timer stil working……  why？ thank you  for your time!!

Comment: Have you set breakpoints? Is your code being processed properly?

Answer (score 3):

I think you didn't set `timer` value

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1,
                         target: self,
                         selector:#selector(ViewController.action),
                         userInfo: nil,
                         repeats: true)
```

Comment: god，you 're right!  now ,this code working!! thank you very much. two day I  in this quesstion.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are invalidating correct instance of Timer. 
Like in `start function`, you didn't assign timer instance to any object, but in `stop function`,you are using `timer` vaiable to stop that timer.
Which means you try to invalidate a variable, which never instantiated.

Still try below function to stop timer, **after assigning timer variable**.

```
@IBAction func stop(_ sender: UIButton) {

       start = false
       timer.invalidate()
       timer = nil
       time = 0
    }
```

Hope this work

Answer (score 0):

First you have to declare it as fileprivate as below:

```
fileprivate var timer = Timer()

@IBAction func start(_ sender: UIButton) {

        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 4,
                                                      target: self,
                                                      selector: #selector(self.updateTimerForLocation),
                                                      userInfo: nil,
                                                      repeats: true)

}

@IBAction func stop(_ sender: UIButton) {

   timer.invalidate()


}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are confusing between variable stop and func stop. 
also you dont need 2 parameter to manage stop/start status

--
for your question,
you should retain the timer variable to able to use it in other func
declare a global timer

`var timer: Timer!`

then

`timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1,
                         target: self,
                         selector:#selector(ViewController.action),
                         userInfo: nil,
                         repeats: true)`

now you can invalidate it anywhere